# Java messageDigest funky output

Tags: java, message-digest

I'm using Java's MessageDigest to do a hashing project. I want to create collisions with hashes made by randomly generated strings. I have verified that my strings are truly random. When I output the digest however it always begins with "[B@" for some reason and when I'm trying to detect a collision with 8 bits obviously everything starts with "[". Here is my code:

```
public boolean encrypt(String x) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("x is " + x);
    java.security.MessageDigest d = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    d.update(x.getBytes());
    d.reset();
    String result = d.digest().toString() + "     ";
    char[] tempCharArray = result.toCharArray();
    String bitArray = "";
    for(int i=0; i< tempCharArray.length; i++){
        bitArray += String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(tempCharArray[i] &
          0xff)).replace(' ', '0');
    }

    result = bitArray.substring(0,8);
    return result;
}
```

Has anyone seen this before/ know what to do to get it right? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You look to be doing some strange stuff in your code.

First, you call;

```
String result = d.digest().toString()
```

..which is going to give you the [string representation of a byte array object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()), which is made of the class name, an "@" symbol, and the hashcode. [Arrays have a class name of "[B"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName()), hence you will always get something starting "[B@".

Secondly you call `d.update(x.getBytes())` and then immediately call `d.reset()`. Even if you fix the first problem you are digesting nothing, irrespective of the value of `x`, so you will always get the same result, [the SHA-1 hash of an empty string](http://www.md5center.com/sha1-reverse-index.php), which is `da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709`.